# Convergence of the following sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

> > For $n \ge 1$, let $$g_n(x) = \sin^2 \left (x + \frac 1 n \right ), x \in [0,\infty)$$ and $$f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{x} g_n (t)\ \mathrm {dt}.$$  Then
> >
> > $(1)$ $\{f_n \}$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, but does not converge uniformly on $[0, \infty)$.
> >
> > $(2)$ $\{f_n \}$ does not converge pointwise to any function $f$ on $[0, \infty)$.
> >
> > $(3)$ $\{f_n \}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.
> >
> > $(4)$ $\{f_n \}$ converges uniformly on $[0, \infty)$.

I have found that $f_n (x) = \frac 1 2 \left (x - \sin x \cos \left (x + \frac 2 n \right ) \right)$ which converges to the function $f$ on $[0, \infty)$ defined by $f(x) = \frac 1 4 ( 2x - \sin {2x}), x \in [0, \infty)$. But I am not quite sure about whether this convergence is uniform or not. Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I have edited my body.

Comment: What is the definition of uniform convergence, and how is it different from point-wise convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$\sin^2(t+\frac 1n)=\frac{1-\cos(2t+\frac 2n)}{2}$$

$$f_n(x)=\int_0^x\sin^2(t+\frac 1n)dt=\frac{1}{2}\Big[t-\frac{\sin(2t+\frac 2n)}{2}\Bigr]_0^x$$

$$=\frac x2-\frac 14\sin(2x+\frac 2n)+\frac 14\sin(\frac 2n)$$

The pointwise limit is
$$f(x)=\frac x2-\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}$$

For the uniform convergence, use MVT to get

$$|\sin(2x+\frac 2n)-\sin(2x)|\le \frac 2n$$

and

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \frac 1n.$$

The convergence is uniform at $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: I have done that. First see my body and then answer.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Your $f_n(x)$ is not correct.

Comment: Have you evaluated your integral between the limits $0$ and $x$?

Comment: In place of $t$ we have $t + \frac 1 n$.

Comment: Now calculate and simplify.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Look now the expression of $f_n(x)$.

Comment: Use the identity $:$ $\sin A - \sin B = 2 \cos \left ( \frac {A+B} {2} \right ) \sin \left (\frac {A-B} {2} \right)$.

Comment: Then compare with my answer in the body.

Comment: The pointwise limit you have just mentioned exactly matches with that of my answer. Please don't misguide me.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I gave a hint about uniform convergence. sorry.

Comment: So according to your answer $|f_n (x) - f(x)| \leq \frac 1 n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ which doesn't depend on which point we choose. Right? So $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0, \infty)$. Am I right?

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Yes. {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have misunderstood you. I apologize for that.

Comment: @DougM What do you say about uniform convergence.